# How to get products in columns in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am not getting a products in columns I am getting in single column by using bootstrap.
How I use grid system in bootstrap so that I can get products in columns wise.

Comment: Can you please share code?

Comment: Sorry sir it is saying that I need at least 10 reputation to post image actually today only first time I asked question here.

Comment: Now what should I do?

Comment: I am using col-md-4 and under this m fetching all details off all products now how can I get them I one row I want 3 products.how it will be possible??

Answer (score 0):

We can create col based layout as per below code.
As per my understanding you need different cols in one row. correct?

```
        <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also have look on below url bootstrap grid.

```
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/
```

I hope will work for you or can reach again.

Comment: Yes exactly different columns in one row but the question is how I can close the div before completion of while loop???

Comment: For static purpose it is fine but if m fetching products from database then how it will be possible??

Comment: if you are looping and generating cols dynamic then add your loop on <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div> going to use JS or angular?

Comment: i am not getting any solution please help me anyone.

Comment: Sir what do I do I can't able to sent code.since I'm new on this site.

Comment: Okay I will trysir  wait

Comment: Now it is saying that my code is not properly intended.when i am trying to copy paste the code from editor.

Comment: Now what should i do??